# How to group an array of subdocuments by multiple fields?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have spent the better part of the day on this and am now out of ideas. Here is my collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "ID_XXX",
    "logs": [
      {
        "lead_id": 123,
        "list_id": "list_44",
        "order_id": "order_1"
      },
      {
        "lead_id": 124,
        "list_id": "list_44",
        "order_id": "order_2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "ID_YYY",
    "logs": [
      {
        "lead_id": 125,
        "list_id": "list_44",
        "order_id": "order_2"
      },
      {
        "lead_id": 126,
        "list_id": "list_44",
        "order_id": "order_2"
      },
      {
        "lead_id": 127,
        "list_id": "list_44",
        "order_id": "order_3"
      },
      {
        "lead_id": 128,
        "list_id": "list_66",
        "order_id": "order_3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm just trying to get the counts for `list_id` and `order_id` while preserving the `_id` of the document they are in. Here is my desired output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "ID_XXX",
    "counts": [
      {
        "lists": {"list_44": 2},
      },
      {
        "orders": {"order_1": 1, "order_2": 1}
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "ID_YYY",
    "counts": [
      {
        "lists": {"list_44": 3, "list_66": 1},
      },
      {
        "orders": {"order_2": 2, "order_3": 2}
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried way too many aggregate variations to list here, but the latest is this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$logs"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      lists: {
        $push: "$logs.list_id"
      },
      orders: {
        $push: "$logs.order_id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Which does not give me what I want. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here is the playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/f-jk7lbSrJ0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `logs`, convert `logs` object to array in k(key) v(value) format using `$objectToArray`, `$concatArrays` with initialValue in `$reduce`,
- `$filter` above reduce result as input and filter required fields from `logs`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `logs` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      logs: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$logs",
              initialValue: [],
              in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", { $objectToArray: "$$this" }] }
            }
          },
          cond: { $in: ["$$this.k", ["list_id", "order_id"]] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$logs" },
```

- `$group` by `_id` and `logs` object and get the total count using `$sum`

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        logs: "$logs"
      },
      counts: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
```

- `$group` by `_id` and make `lists` array if `logs.k` is `list_id` and return in k and v format otherwise `$$REMOVE`, same as for `orders` make an array of order on the base of `order_id`
- `$addFields` to convert `lists` array from k and v format to object format using $arrayToObject`and same as for`orders` array

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      lists: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            { $eq: ["$_id.logs.k", "list_id"] },
            {
              k: "$_id.logs.v",
              v: "$counts"
            },
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      },
      orders: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            { $eq: ["$_id.logs.k", "order_id"] },
            {
              k: "$_id.logs.v",
              v: "$counts"
            },
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      lists: { $arrayToObject: "$lists" },
      orders: { $arrayToObject: "$orders" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1dcuOl6_h9n)

Comment: This works, thank you. But given the relative complexity of this aggregation, would you recommend that I instead pull the raw data into my code and do this in JS instead of aggregating it? I'm just wondering what you think would be more efficient.

Comment: this is just a logic you can do it your client side language and it would be efficient than query, and if you really want to do in aggregation then try [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator, you can do JS code inside this function.

Comment: Got it. My concern doing this on the client side is that those logs can contain hundreds of thousands of entries and, since my database is not on the same server as my node app, I did not want to download all that data into my application to do stuff with it. Either way, really appreciate your insight.